# Python stops working on loadmat

Tags: python, scipy

I'm having trouble using SciPy's loadmat. while savemat seems to work fine, when I try to load any .mat file, the whole python simply stops working without even throwing an error.
I'm using anaconda2 distro (python 2.7) with scipy 0.17.0.

```
from scipy import io
dict_a = {'a':[3, 9, 17, 15, 19]}
io.savemat('example.mat', dict_a)

mat = io.loadmat('example.mat')
```

This example crashes the python on the last line. I would be glad for any ideas.

Comment: I would try to step into `io.loadmat()` and then go step by step in order to narrow down what is going wrong. Also, have a look at the other [arguments](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html), you may be missing some other info?

Comment: I just tried your code and it works fine with me. So never mind about the other arguments. You say it *crashes the python*, but no error message appears at all? I tried with Python 2.7.5 and scipy 0.11. I will try to run the same example on 0.17.

Comment: Ok, so I installed `scipy 0.17.0` on a `virtualenv` and your code still runs just fine. I've just noticed a small difference in `mat.__repr__()` (the output of `mat`), when compared to `0.11`. I guess you really need to do more tests to figure out where the issue is coming from. Perhaps you could also try it in a clean `virtualenv`.

Comment: Yes, when I say it crashes the python I mean the python.exe actually stops working. It does however throw an error in the output I didn't notice (I'm VERY new to python and visual studio in general).
The program '[5700] python.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: When I tried stepping into the mio.py, it crashes on followin if-statement:

`if mdict is not None:
        mdict.update(matfile_dict)
    else:
        mdict = matfile_dict`

Comment: That seems odd. I think that error is related to python trying to write in a memory address that it shouldn't. Where does it crash exactly? In the condition evaluation, in the `then`, or in the `else`? Please try to run it outside visual studio and see what happens. Sorry, I don't have more ideas, also I don't have visual studio nor windows, so I can't reproduce your environment.

Comment: It crashes on `mdict = matfile_dict`. I tried it through python console instead of VS - same result. Clean instalation - same result. Reproduce on different system - same result. Tried it on Anaconda3 (python 3.5) - it worked fine. I would stick to python3 but AFAIK there's no way to make it work with VTK for now, so I guess I'll have to work around it by saving the .mat files as .csv instead... Anyway, thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Ok, let's try one more thing, which seems dumb but we can try. Try to pass the target `dict` as the second argument of `io.loadmat()`. Something like this: `mat2 = {}` and then `io.loadmat('example.mat', mat2)`. The dict `mat2` will be updated in-place, no need for `mat 2 = io.loadmat(...)`. This will also prevent the faulty line to be executed. However, I'll be surprised if this works... let me know!

Comment: I already thought of that and tried it to no avail. I solved the issue however by downgrading to Anaconda 2.4.1. It's weird because the mio.py still contains exactly the same if-statement but everything works fine now. Again thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble seems to be caused by faulty version of Anaconda 2.5.0, after downgrading to Anaconda 2.4.1 (or upgrading to Anaconda3) loadmat works properly.

Comment: I'm glad you found out a solution. You can mark your own answer as the accepted one, just click the green tick on the left side of the answer. Also, it would be nice if you fill a [bug report on their tracker](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues), or perhaps look if that issue is already addressed there.

Comment: [The problem has been reported](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/650)

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this issue after updating scipy.
Downgrading scipy to 0.16.0 solved the issue.

```
conda install scipy==0.16.0
```

also see this post
[github](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/650)

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely the same problem. Win 10, Anaconda 2.5.0 and scipy.io.loadmat(...)
I've debugged down to mio5.py line 217:
mdtype, byte_count = self._file_reader.read_full_tag()

Further on I can't event step into this function.

Posted information to github/anaconda-issues

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by upgrading to scipy 0.190, while other people solved it by downgrading to 0.16.0, so my guess is that there is something wrong with scipy version 0.17.0.