# scipy.io.loadmat doesn't work

Tags: python, scipy

I have some problems loading mat files into spyder environment. I update my conda version and OS system (now I have Windows 10) and my script doesn't work anymore.

This is the script:

```
import scipy.io as sio
# I do a lot of stuff here
file = "filename.mat"
a = sio.loadmat(file)
```

I have found that there is a problem with the `loadmat` routine, but I don't know what.

I have this information about the system:

- OS: Windows 10, 64 bits.
- Anaconda 2, python 2.7
- Other related software installed: Visual Studio 2015

It works before system operation update. Previus version was Windows 7, 64 bits

The error message when load line is executing: "Apparently the core died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart the core' to continue using this terminal."

UPDATE 1:

I have tested in a laptop the same situation, i.e., windows updating as well anaconda. The same problem with scipy.io.loadmat

UPDATE 2:

I installed an older version of anaconda. IT WORKS!!... Does somebody know what to do now?

Regards

Comment: How does it not *work* anymore? Post the traceback if you get some error.

Comment: Hi, 

I had windows 7 and, with anaconda, all was wonderful. I have a script that load a matlab file, which has a matrix whit several columns and near to 180,000 rows. I process that data and make some plots. However, when I update to windows 10, and update Anaconda to the last one, I tried to run my example script. I discover that it crush exactly when matlab file was loading. The message is something like "Kore suddenly crush..." (I'm not in my PC and the original message is in spanish... sorry). That's all.

Comment: The information must be more specific, i.e., all the things that changed between the old system and the new: 32bit vs 64bit, Anaconda version, scipy version, etc. We'll also need the actual and full error message. Either post it here in English, or post your question in [Spanish SO](http://es.stackoverflow.com/). By the way, if you want to add any new information, edit your question to make it more visible, don't add it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, Reti43. I'll do my best next time

Comment: I have the same problem, unfortunately... Everything was working fine on Win7, now that I updated to Win10 and reinstalled Anaconda, loadmat kills the kernel (no traceback, just kernel dead). ;(

Comment: found this: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/650

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python stops working on loadmat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238878/python-stops-working-on-loadmat)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in the new `scipy`. You should downgrade it by running this in the Command Prompt:

```
conda install scipy==0.16.0
```